# E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, ip, oracle-sqldeveloper

Acabo de instalar `OracleXE184` en un pc recién formateado, también baje la ultima versión de `SQL Developer`.
Resulta que cuando intento crear una conexión a una base de datos me muestra el mensaje de error puesto en la pregunta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya comprobé que, efectivamente, el `listener` esta funcionando y que esta utilizando el puerto **1521**, la base de datos es `local`.

Archivo tnsnames.ora:

```
    XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Leo.home)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Leo.home)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Archivo listener.ora:

```
  DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Leonardo\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Leonardo\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Leo.home)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

En cuanto a los servicios de Oracle, todos funcionan con excepción de uno llamado `OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener`, este servicio no se inicia por más veces que lo intente.

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque pedir ayuda urgente es descortés y hasta grosero](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152/21).

Comment: Por favor, no publiques imágenes del texto de tus archivos de configuración, publica el texto como tal (utiliza el formato de código). Un saludo.